# How to get the value of a variable out of the scope of the arrow function which created it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

So, i have this code:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (msg) => {
  if (msg.content.startsWith("-p")) {
    if (!msg.member.voice?.channel) return msg.channel.send("Por favor...");
    const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
      channelId: msg.member.voice.channel.id,
      guildId: msg.guild.id,
      adapterCreator: msg.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
    });
    google
      .youtube("v3")
      .search.list({
        key: process.env.YOUTUBE_TOKEN,
        part: "id",
        q: msg.content.slice(3),
        maxResults: 1,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const { data } = response;
        let link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + data.items.id.videoId;
      });
    let args = msg.content.slice(3);
    let stream = await play.stream(args);
    let resource = createAudioResource(stream.stream, {
      inputType: stream.type,
    });
    let player = createAudioPlayer({
      behaviors: {
        noSubscriber: NoSubscriberBehavior.Play,
      },
    });
    player.play(resource);
    connection.subscribe(player);
  }
});
```

And I would like to use the value of the variable "link", which is a string, as a parameter for the method **play.stre(args)**

I'm don't fully understand how to get that done

Also, if possible I would like to find a way to store that value too inside an array outside the whole:

```
*client.on('messageCreate' , async msg => {...   ...})*
```

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to call `play.stream` from within the `then` callback of `list`:

```js
google.youtube("v3")
  .search.list({
    key: process.env.YOUTUBE_TOKEN,
    part: "id",
    q: msg.content.slice(3),
    maxResults: 1,
  })
  .then(async (response) => {
    const { data } = response;
    let link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + data.items.id.videoId;
    let stream = await play.stream(link);
  });
```

Like this, you'll make sure that you actually have a value set for `link` when using it to call `stream`.

Comment: By doing that i get another error "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules"

Comment: That's just because the `then` callback was not async. I added the `async` keyword now, but that's just a quick fix. I would recommend to refactor into using `async/await` in general, that'll allow you to clean up a lot.

Comment: @CristianDavidMoraleda I would also suggest to take a minute to read up on [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await). It can be confusing but it's important you fully understand it, or you'll be in a lot of pain trying to do this

Comment: After putting the "play.stream" inside the then callback of list, the method createAudioResource() says now that the variable "stream" is undefined

Comment: You'll need to adapt the rest of your code. I'm not trying to refactor your code for you but to give you an idea of a concept.